# How is $\displaystyle{x\times (0,1)}$ open in $I_0^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Take $I_0^2=[0,1]\times[0,1]$. How is $\displaystyle{x\times (0,1)}$ an open set in $I_0^2$?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean $\{x\}\times (0,1)$ in $I_0^2$ with the usual topology, it isn't open.

Comment: Munkres on pg.172 says " let $f:[a,b]\to I_0^2$. By continuity, $f^{-1}(x\times (0,1))$ is open". I assume that by this, he means that $x\times (0,1)$ is open in $I_0^2$.

Comment: $I_0\times(0,1)$, perhaps?

Comment: @DavidMitra- The comment above was addressed to you.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking It is open in the lexicographical order topology, as it is an open interval bounded by $(x,0)$ and $(x,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by $x$ you mean a single value in $[0, 1]$, it is not an open set because you cannot find a ball of positive radius which is a subset of $\{x\} \times (0, 1)$ around each point (in fact, you can't find such a ball for any point). It is also not a closed set because there exists a sequence $\{(x, \frac{1}{2^n})\}_n$ which approaches the point $(x, 0)$, so it does not contain all its limit points.

Comment: @Tony- Munkres on pg.172 says " let $f:[a,b]→I^2_0$. By continuity, $f^{−1}(x\times (0,1))$ is open". I assume that by this, he means that $x\times (0,1)$ is open in $I^2_0$.